# WPF add elements to DataGrid from template

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to figure out how templates in WPF works. Is it possible to transform this:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="AppSettingsTextBoxes" Grid.Row="7" Style="{StaticResource AppSettingsDataGridStyle}" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Element Name" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value}" Header="Value" Width="*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Comment}" Header="Comment" Width="4*" IsReadOnly="True" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

into something like this:

```
 <Grid.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TextBoxGridTemplate">
        <DataGrid>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Element Name" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value}" Header="Value" Width="*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Comment}" Header="Comment" Width="4*" IsReadOnly="True" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </DataTemplate>
 </Grid.Resources>
...
<DataGrid x:Name="AppSettingsTextBoxes" Grid.Row="7" Style="{StaticResource AppSettingsDataGridStyle}" (???)DataTemplate ="{StaticResource TextBoxGridTemplate}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to transform ...

No.

`AppSettingsTextBoxes` is an instance of a `DataGrid` and not a `DataTemplate`. And you can't define `DataGrid` columns in a `DataTemplate`.

If you want to reuse the same columns in several different places, you could consider creating a custom `DataGrid` class that creates these columns programmatically:

```
public class CustomDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    public CustomDataGrid()
    {
        Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Binding = new Binding("Name"), Header = "Element Name" });
    }
}
```

You can then create instances of this class in your XAML:

But you can't define instances of columns in your XAML and then reuse this XAML in several `DataGrids`.